# How can I resize the figure automatically to be tight around the plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axis, figure

I am using the `axis tight` command, and then copying the figure to word. The problem is that the plot is tight but the figure itself is a rectangle, and there is just a lot of space wasted for just the framework around.

So, I am copying the full figure to Paint, cutting it there for the plot only and then pasting it in Word, not fun as I have a lot of those. Any ideas?

Illustration of copied figure:

[image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwE-Ba3ePCwOb0VrSnVZcG5YMlE/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: Can you also give a screenshot how the "original" window looks?

Comment: sure https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwE-Ba3ePCwOekRvMUF3dmVsdGc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: funny how it does that. Maybe it's to do with paint or so. What steps do you do exactly when you "copy" it to paint?

Comment: o,I think I didnt explain myself right ,its not the paint that doing that,but the "axis tight" command itself. Im using paint just to cut the axis itself from the huge figure that matlab print.

Comment: What `axis tight` does in your case is very non-standard. It should keep the `axes` in place and make the scale so the lines will fill the axis. In your case it seems to keep the lines and shrink the axes. Could it be you have some callbacks added to your figure or its children?

Comment: no , not in these case. Anyway thanks for the help , I guess its cut and paste for me ...

Comment: @bdecaf, I noticed that too so I tried to reproduce his example and I get the same thing if I use both `axis tight` **and** `axis equal` for my figure. Roman, could you confirm if this is the case for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Position` properties of the axis directly to fit it to the figure:

```
>> set( gca, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0 0 1 1] );
```

Comment: thats still keeps the figure windows itself huge relative to the plot. I get rectangular plot ,in a square huge figure

Comment: please post some images demonstrating the issue. it is difficult to answer your question without visualizing the problem.

Comment: @Roman BTW, you have an image cropping tool built-in in MS word, so you do not need to go through Paint.

Comment: i tried to upload it , but the forum rules says something about me posted too little to upload a picture ,can I send it to you by mail?

Comment: sorry ,dont know how to do that

Comment: try uploading to a host (like http://tinypic.com/) then post the link to the uploaded image.

Comment: now I understand what you mean... https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwE-Ba3ePCwOb0VrSnVZcG5YMlE/edit?usp=sharing , the gray around the main plot is the size of the figure

Comment: You need to assure gca actually refers to the plot axis. Maybe that's one problem. also `get(gca,'TightInset')` will give you the minimum width you will need for the axes label.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here. But I believe you are taking the figure from some gui.

I would use `copyobj` to transfer the axis to another empty figure. For this you can set all the parameters as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and changing `Position` or `axis tight` hasn't worked for me either, so I crop my images using [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/). (free)

Typically I don't have many images to crop at once, so I do them individually, but I think you could batch crop to a set size using an ImageJ macro. It'd be Process > Batch > Macro… and then in "Add Macro Code" choose Crop and specify the position and dimensions of the rectangle. (At least in ImageJ v1.46r)

I know it's not quite what you asked for, but it is a work-around. If someone else has an all-Matlab solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the figure, have you tried saving it directly in MATLAB?  In the figure window, if you go to File/Save As.., you have the option of saving as either a MATLAB .fig or in a variety of standard image formats.

Alternately, I also highly recommend Yair Altman's export_fig, which is available at https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig, which is great for creating publication quality figures.

Comment: Sorry for the thread necromancy.. the post is listed as modified today and so popped up on my start screen.  I didn't see the dates of the original post and replies until after I posted.